# CSS How to avoid one element style actual one (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a User menu dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="badge badge-success pull-right">5</span> Settings </a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Lock screen</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>

                            @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"> Logout</a></li>
                            }
                        </ul>
```

Adding the `@Html.BeginForm` breaks the style of my dropdown.

[image]

> Any clue on how can I avoid that for adding extra styling to my dropdown element?

Comment: Not quite enough information to go by. Can you copy/paste the contents of `.dropdown-menu` from the rendered HTML in your browser's development tools?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are putting a form that breaks your list layout, put the form inside the `<li></li>`

a list have to have layout

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

`@html.beginform` does actually render a form so your html will look like

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <form>
   <li><a href="#0"></a></li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

so change to this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="badge badge-success pull-right">5</span> Settings </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Lock screen</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li> @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
       { 
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"> Logout</a>
       }
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I just follow your instructions and still the same style issue. This is the code:
<li>
<form action="" method="post"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"> Logout</a>
</form>                            </li>

Comment: @VAAA then post your css and a jsfiddle for demo then I can look closer.